# How to manipulate images with SFML?

Tags: c++, image, sfml

I'm working on a game and I need to draw a sequence of tiles into a `sf::Image`, but the only way I could draw something into a `sf::Image` (or `sf::Texture`) was by editing the pixels directly.

I'd like to know if there is any function like the `SDL_BlitSurface` or something like that in SFML. The only object I could draw things on was the `sf::RenderWindow`.

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting about something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sf::RenderTexture` to call `Draw` functions with any drawable and take the result as a `sf::Texture`. You can then convert the `sf::Texture` to a `sf::Image`. Just take a look in documentation.

Comment: Wow, I'm feeling kinda stupid. I was using 1.6, so I didn't know that there were "RenderTextures"... That worked like a charm for me... Thanks :)